# excel vba select multiple columns in a loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, multiple-columns, execution-time

**Edit**: I only have 28,000 columns, and you all are correct that they can't all fit in one worksheet. I was testing my code with only a portion of the data and hadn't yet realized that it will not all fit

I have **28,000** columns of data. I am trying to to copy specific columns 5,12,19,26...(ie for i=1:4000, column number = 7*(i-1) + 5). My original thought is below, but the problem is that after each iteration of the loop, the previous column is deselected. So the code below does not copy the intended data.

```
For i = 1 To 4000
    DataSheet.Columns(7 * (i - 1) + 5).Select
Next i

Selection.Copy
ResultsSheet.Paste
```

I thought about the alternative below (which works, but very slowly), but I was hoping I could write something that executes more quickly (part of the problem is the code selects the destination sheet and pastes each column individually, essentially quadrupling the number of steps as something similar to the first solution).

```
For i = 1 To nSymbols
    DataSheet.Columns(7 * (i - 1) + 5).Copy
    ResultsSheet.Select
    Columns(i+1).Select        
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
```

Any ideas on how to make this code run (faster)?

Comment: Please supply the version of Excel that you are using. My Excel 2016 only has 16,384 columns per worksheet, not '*32,000 columns of data*' or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use Union and increment your For ... Next by 7 for each increment.

```
dim c as long, rng as range

with worksheets("sheet1")
    set rng = intersect(.columns(5), .usedrange)
    for c = 12 to 4000 step 7
        set rng = UNION(rng,  intersect(.columns(c), .usedrange))
    next c
end with

debug.print rng.address(0, 0)
rng.copy destination:=ResultsSheet.cells(2, 1)
```

I've added Intersect with UsedRange to reduce the full column references. Due to the Union'ed range, this Copy & Paste resjults in a Copy, Paste Special, Values and fORMATS.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be `to 4000`, rather `7*(4000-1)+5` so `to 27998`?

Comment: Yeah, I just caught that on a reread. It might be to big for a union but I'm checking now.

Comment: @CallumDA - I'll wait for the OP to explain further. My Excel 2016 only has 16,384 columns per worksheet.

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it turns out